# LinkedIn Video Analytics API - timeRange invalid

Tags: parameters, linkedin-api, http-status-code-400

Using the linkedIn Video Analytics API, I want to gather analytics about my video post per day.

My request:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/videoAnalytics?q=entity&entity=urn:li:ugcPost:6662300354706755584&type=VIEWER&timeRange=(start:1588416100,end:1590624000)&aggregation=DAY
```

However, I keep receiving the following error:

```
{"message":"Parameter 'timeRange' is invalid","status":400}
```

I tried changing the timeRange from miliseconds to epoch time, but that did not make a difference. Please, can anyone help to solve this issue here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the timeRange in two different query string params:

So, instead of:

```
&timeRange=(start:1588416100,end:1590624000)&...
```

You could use:

```
&timeRange.start=1588416100&timeRange.end:1590624000&...
```

So the final url could be:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/videoAnalytics?q=entity&entity=urn:li:ugcPost:6662300354706755584&type=VIEWER&timeRange.start:1588416100&timeRange.end:1590624000&aggregation=DAY
```

I've tried with success. Hope this works for you

NB: Remember that timestamp is in milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the version of Restli-Protocol-Version" you are using 
if you are using Restli 1.0. then your request should look like this

```
&timeIntervals.timeGranularityType=DAY&timeIntervals.timeRange.start=1551398400000&timeIntervals.timeRange.end=1552003200000
```

if you are using Restli 2.0 then your request should look like this

```
&timeIntervals=(timeRange:(start:1551398400000,end:1552003200000),timeGranularityType:DAY)
```

Comment: Interesting, I've tried adding the header about. the Restli api version without any success. Could you please improve your answer about the requested endpoint? Thanks!