# How to get video statistics in Linkedin API?

Tags: linkedin-api

according to the documentation for Linkedin API, this is the call:
`https://api.linkedin.com/rest/videoAnalytics?aggregation=DAY&q=entity&entity=urn:li:ugcPost:70434434109261312&type=VIDEO_VIEW&timeRange=(start: 1680114336897,end: 1680197809541)`

but I get an error :
`Parameter 'timeRange' is invalid`

if omit this parameter it works.

Any idea?

The Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/video-analytics-api?view=li-lms-2023-03&tabs=http

Comment: there's mention on that page of the timerange data only being available for six months, and your timestamps are from 2018. If you try a more recent time range does it work?

Comment: I tried with (start:1680114336897,end:1680197809541) - less then 6 months, but still is not working

Comment: does the solution posed in this question help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62082188/linkedin-video-analytics-api-timerange-invalid
?

Comment: it works. Thanks a lot, @TZHX . so weird the documentation is written else